# Which Collection shall i use here?

Tags: java, collections

Phonebook contains number and name. I will appreciate, if anyone help me to choose best Collection, which will help me to perform

1. Add Name and Number.
2. Search Name by Number
3. Remove Name and Number by Name.

Currently i'm using HashMap, but here both name and number will be key, which wont be good. Another option is to wrap both name and number in an object and then add them to the list.And then Iterating and adding to the list. But if you can suggest me some other Collection that can be best one, I shall do that.

**Note : -** Name and Number are String

Comment: what is string? Is it name? Do you want to store names as string with numbers as key?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the name, number and string

Comment: @user1898282 so don't write like that way. be clear with your question. So that, we need not think about your question (what exactly you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need querying by both the name and phone number, then it is indeed possible and quite simple to put all the name-number pairs into a list, but both the search and remove will have a **linear** complexity.

If you want better time complexity (for example constant or at least logarithmic), you might want to use a bidirectional map. For example, Guava's [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) provides exactly this behaviour.

In case you need to implement this yourself (if it's a homework for example), I would create a class that consists of two inner `HashMap`s, one for each direction of the entry. This will give you **constant-time** lookup for both name and number. Of course, you have to make sure that you keep both the maps in sync at all times.

```
public class PhoneBook {

    private Map<String, String> namesToNumbers = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> numbersToNames = new HashMap<>();

    public void insertEntry(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        namesToNumbers.put(name, phoneNumber);
        numbersToNames.put(phoneNumber, name);
    }

    public String getNameForPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return numbersToNames.get(phoneNumber);
    }

    public String getPhoneNumberForName(String name) {
        return namesToNumbers.get(name);
    }

    public void removeEntryByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        String name = numbersToNames.get(phoneNumber);
        namesToNumbers.remove(name);
        numbersToNames.remove(phoneNumber);
    }

    public void removeEntryByName(String name) {
        String phoneNumber = namesToNumbers.get(name);
        numbersToNames.remove(phoneNumber);
        namesToNumbers.remove(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Hashtable is (mostly) needlessly synchronized, which has some performance overhead. HashMap is faster. However, both of them implement the `Map` interface, so if you declare your variables with Map type, then you can easily interchange the implementation.

Comment: Creating two hashmaps...that's space overhead...is there any other way??

Comment: @user1898282 Well, many programming problems involve compromises between memory and CPU complexity. Solution with two maps is time-wise optimal, but for the cost of memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an object as using it would add more scope further down the line should you need to store more than name and number. You can write some helper functions to get the data you require.

Answer (score 0):

You still can use HashMap K=Number V=Name, since search speed logically is more important, and you can use iterator to delete by name, something like

```
Iterator i = map.entrySet().iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    Entry e = i.next();
    if (e.getValue().equals("user1898282") {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```